# React access one components function from another

Tags: reactjs

I am building a react app and have two functional components which do not have a parent/ child relationship.

Component one renders a canvas element and has functions which alter that element.

Component two is for the UI and has buttons which I want to trigger component one's functions.

The app is quite complex and I want to keep all the canvas functions in one place not in the global app scope.

My question is how do I reference component one functions in component two.

Component one:

```
export default function CanvasElement() {

    let drawImage = () =>  {
        /* Alter canvas */
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <canvas id="image-region-canvas"></canvas> 
        </div>
    )
}
```

Component two:

```
export default function UIElement() {

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={canvasElement.drawImage}></button> 
        </div>
    )
}
```

App.js:

```
 class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="card-designer">
                <CanvasElement/>
                <UIElement/>
            </div>
        );
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to shift the `drawImage()` function up to the App component and pass this as props to both or essentially UIElement.

Comment: Is there any other way of sharing the functions.  I want to keep the app object oriented and have all the canvas functions in one place.

Comment: Not Sure but try reading about React Context API https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html it may help if possible. Otherwise generally data cannot flow from down to Up in react, its always up to down.

Comment: Yes, I thought of the context API, though it seems logical to have the canvas functions in the canvas component.

Comment: Or the better option will be to nest the UIElement inside the CanvasElement and pass functions as props.

Answer (score 0):

You should treat `<App>` like a container, or wrap both child components in a container parent inside `<App>`. Then, place the functions in the parent and pass what they return as props to CanvasElement. That way you can call the functions using button clicks and pass the result to the other child.

Comment: The issue is that the canvas functions are just one small part of the app, if I put all of the functions in a container above UI/Canvas it will get very confusing.

Comment: Well, usually apps are made up of very many small parts, or at least in general it's good idea to try and make it that way! You could also create a'util' or 'service' file, there you place the functions and export them. That way you can access them from anywhere in your application and make it more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a container component?

```
export default function Container() {

    let drawImage = () =>  {
        /* Alter canvas */
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <CanvasElement/>
            <UIElement drawImage={drawImage}/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

To better re-usability you have to use both presentation components and container components. 
All the business logic or data manipulation needs to handle by container components. Presentation components are only responsible for displaying the data that get from props.

So with the above implementation, you can keep all your business logic data in one place (In this case, inside the container component) Then you can pass down any necessary things as props to child components.

Comment: The issue is that the canvas functions are just one small part of the app, if I put all of the functions in a container above UI/Canvas it will get very confusing.  Ideally I want all the canvas functions in one file.

Comment: This is how Facebook handle their front end code using React. This is the recommended way to do that. Passing props down to presentation components. I assume that your application is not bigger than Facebook application.